# Read blob file in base64 and upload on the server

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, blob, react-dropzone

When I drop a file in the upload area, the [React-dropzone](https://github.com/react-dropzone/react-dropzone) returns an object such as:

```
let picture = [
    {
        "rawFile": {
            "preview": "blob:http://localhost:3000/ff851b03-b2c0-4212-9240-8d07057ad47d"
        },
        "src": "blob:http://localhost:3000/ff851b03-b2c0-4212-9240-8d07057ad47d",
        "title": "1397-01-20 13.43.24.jpg"
    }
]
```

I read this link and try to upload the file: [React dropzone, how to upload image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41025078/react-dropzone-how-to-upload-image?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

But I think the file will not be sent.

This is my code:

```
let formData = new FormData();
formData.append('file', picture[0]);
fetch('http://localhost:8000/api/media', {
 method: 'POST',
 body: formData
});
```

If this method is not correct, How to send the file to the server side and receive it on the server side?

On the server side, I'm using Hapij.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved the problem. I write the answer because anybody didn't answer this question.

In the client side, I use the `FileReader` API to read the BLOB data and convert it to `base64` readable format. I write a function to convert blob to base64 and send `fileName` and `base64` to the server side.

```
const convertFileToBase64 = file => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const reader = new FileReader();
    reader.readAsDataURL(file.rawFile);

    reader.onload = () => resolve({
        fileName: file.title,
        base64: reader.result
    });
    reader.onerror = reject;
});
```

On the server side, I write the buffer to the file by this function:

```
const fs = require("fs");
const Boom = require('boom');

function convertBase64ToFile(file) {

  let base64Data = file.base64.split(',')[1];

  fs.writeFile(`${__dirname}/../../uploads/${file.fileName}`, base64Data, 'base64', function(err) {
    return Boom.badData(err);
  });

  // Other actions...

}
```

This method works for me perfectly.

Comment: readAsDataURL only accept File or Blob how did you do that whitout exception?!
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader

Comment: @AminRahimi I don't receive any exceptions. I read this link and rewrite code by promise: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6926016/nodejs-saving-a-base64-encoded-image-to-disk

Comment: I don't know react-dropzone, but If this code works, then the one in the question must have worked too. Both methods expect a Blob as input.